Can't find material design icon library for Kotlin
I'm trying to use the extended icon library for Material Design and Kotlin. I've added
material-icons-extended = { group = "androidx.compose.material", name = "material-icons-extended" }

to my libs.versions.toml file under [libraries] and I've added
implementation(libs.material.icons.extended)

to my build.gradle.kts file. When I compile, I get:
Execution failed for task ':composeApp:compileKotlinDesktop'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':composeApp:desktopCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:.
     Required by:
         project :composeApp

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

What am I doing wrong?

You need to specify the dependency version to point out the exact artifact. 1.6.8 is the latest at the time of writing; see the available versions here.
material-icons-extended = { group = "androidx.compose.material", name = "material-icons-extended", version = "1.6.8" }


You should also make sure a repository containing the artifact is declared:
repositories {
    ...
    google()
}


That seems to work, in that fixing it and syncing Gradle downloads and installs the library. But my code doesn't recognize any of the extended icons and refuses to import them.
